# Product of delta functions in fermion self-energy at finite temperature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, dirac-delta-distributions, self-energy, thermal-field-theory

In the calculation of the fermion self-energy at finite temperature, there seems to be a term containing the product of two delta functions which when combined equal zero, however I fail to see why that is the case. The product is of the form:

$$
\int d^4 k\; \delta((p-k)^2-m^2)\delta(k^2)
$$

The main reference I'm using is Donoghue's 1983 article: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.28.340

Notice that in Eq. 06 the term I'm referring to, which would come from the last terms in the cross product $S((p-k)D(k))$, is absent.